# Error when return a variable in typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Goal: I want to eliminate code repetition

here is the code ::

```
export class GoogleService {
  keyFile:string = './src/google/credentials.json';
  scopes:string = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets';
  spreadsheetId:string = 'ABC';

  constructor(private http: HttpService) {}

 
  async writeToGSheets() {
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: this.keyFile,
      scopes: this.scopes,
    });

    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const googleSheet = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: client });
  

    const metaData = await googleSheet.spreadsheets.get({
      auth,
      spreadsheetId:this.spreadsheetId
    });

    const getRows = await googleSheet.spreadsheets.values.get({
      auth,
      spreadsheetId:this.spreadsheetId,
      range: 'Sheet1',
    });

    await googleSheet.spreadsheets.values.append({
      auth,
      spreadsheetId:this.spreadsheetId,
      range: 'Sheet1!A:B',
      valueInputOption: 'RAW',
      requestBody: {
        values: [['1', '2']],
      },
    });
  }

  async readGSheets() {
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: this.keyFile,
      scopes: this.scopes,
    });

    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const googleSheet = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: client });
  

    const metaData = await googleSheet.spreadsheets.get({
      auth,
      spreadsheetId:this.spreadsheetId,
      // range: 'Sheet1!A:B'
    });

    // read rows from spreadsheets

    const getRows = await googleSheet.spreadsheets.values.get({
      auth,
      spreadsheetId:this.spreadsheetId,
      range: 'Sheet1',
    });
    return getRows.data.values;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have a bunch of repetition and I hate it!

I am trying to write out a function for the authentication variable as so::

```
  getAuth(){
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: this.keyFile,
      scopes: this.scopes,
    });
    return auth;
  }
```

However, I get the following error:

```
The inferred type of 'getAuth' cannot be named without a reference to '.pnpm/google-auth-library@8.7.0/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.ts(2742)
```

[image: error]

I don't need to slim down the code, but I really want to further my dev skills and I think this is a good challenge.
I don't understand what the issue is here though lol

Comment: Does typing your function as `getAuth(): google.auth.GoogleAuth { ... }` not solve it?

Comment: negative. new error : Cannot find namespace 'google'.